# Any way to stop automatically wrap <p> tags in medium editor JS?

Tags: javascript, text-editor, medium-editor

Check the below lines that medium editor works

```
<div class="editor">
  <p>this is the <i>first</i> line</p>
  <p>this is a <b>second</b> line</p>
</div>
```

I want like this

```
<div class="editor">
this is the <i>first</i> line<br/>
this is a <b>second</b> line<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the documentation say? What have you tried so far? (What's wrong with those paragraphs?)

Comment: everyone have its own requirement. I'm agreed with current behavior of medium JS. but the person for i work for he never understand that problem.